# Не удаляются куки при закрытии браузера

Tags: php

Проблема собственно в следующем, создается кука с параметром времени 0, в документации php.net говорится следующее

> Если задать 0 или пропустить этот аргумент, срок действия cookie
> истечет с окончанием сессии (при закрытии браузера).

Этот вопрос много где муссировался, но мне не помогло ни установка прошлого времени time()-3600 , ни просто пропуск данного аргумента.

Причем проблема эта во всех браузерах не только в гугле.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
      if (!is_page('age'))
    {
         if( !isset( $_COOKIE['age_boolean'] ))
         {
              wp_redirect(  home_url() . '/age' ,302);
              exit;
         }
    } else
    {
        if (!empty($_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'action_name')
        {
            setcookie('age_boolean','ok', 0, '/');
            wp_redirect(  home_url(), 302);
            exit;
        }
    }
} );
```

Сайт на wp  код  в functions.php все хорошо работает за исключением того что куки не удаляються даже при перезагрузке компа. Может дело в wp?

[image: куки сессионные]

Собственно идея такова есть страница заглушка входа на сайт, при входе на сайт юзер нажимает кнопку на форме отправляется запрос, по наличию которого увстанавливается кука и человек переходит на сайт, если куки нет то юзер попадает на страницу заглушку, поэтому важно что б кука была на одну сессию. Кстати пробовал и через сессию делать, но тоже ничего не вышло.

Comment: все современные браузеры сохраняют сессию. и восстанавливают её при запуске.

Comment: и как быть в таком случае

Answer (score 0):

повесить обработчик на покидание страницы не помогает?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  //unset cookie
};
```

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        document.cookie = "name=age_boolean; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;";
    };` не пмогло